# How to print each element of Multi-line String Parameter by bash shell in Jenkins Job

Tags: bash, jenkins

It is strange while I want to use **Multi-line String Parameter** in Jenkins job.
The parameter name is `PRS_INFO`, and its default text is:

```
PT54321:file xxx not exit
PT74231:xxx reboot
```

After running this job, the parameter is set to environment:

```
PRS_INFO    PT54321:file xxx not exit>PT74231:xxx reboot
```

But when I want to print it line by line using bash shell code like:

```
set -x
IFS_OLD=$IFS
IFS='>'
for i in $PRONTO_INFO; do
  echo $i
done
IFS=$IFS_OLD
```

It prints the log in console:

```
+ IFS_OLD='     
'
+ IFS='>'
+ for i in '$PRS_INFO'
+ echo 'PT54321:file xxx not exit
PT74231:xxx reboot'
PT54321:file xxx not exit
PT74231:xxx reboot 
+ IFS='
```

Why is the `echo` just called once to print all lines, not twice to print two lines?

PS. Jenkins 2.32.3 is the Jenkins version we use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not seem to be a `>` character in your `PRS_INFO` variable;

Try:

```
set -x
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $PRS_INFO; do
    echo "$line"
done
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

Comment: Yes, it works. There is a hidden control character which equals to '\n'  in the `PRS_INFO`.  Maybe Jenkins can not print multi lines when showing **injectedEnvVars** in web pages, so it uses  '>' to separate two lines. Great thanks.

Comment: I have a multi line string x with two lines: abc and 123. The suggested code returns: **set -x
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for line in abc
123
; do
    echo "$line"
done
IFS="$OLD_IFS"] ...
+ OLD_IFS='  
'
+ IFS='
'
bash: -c: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `abc'
bash: -c: line 5: `123'**

Comment: @Heinz could you ask this in a new question and leave the link in a comment here, please? The formatting in comments is not really appropriate for long code blocks and I feel like a little more context would really help address your issue.